# Angular custom component ngModel

Tags: angular

Basically, I want to develop a custom date picker component, which uses another 2 components internally. I have done them, but the problem is that `[(ngModel)]` binding does not work.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wtvijr

Can you help please?
I have

Comment: I think that's because you've specified one property for `ngmodel` meanwhile using other setter/getter name.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dajvfz?file=src/app/app.component.html